# Binding childitem into menu control asp.net

Tags: asp.net, menu

```
DataRow[] drowpar = dt.Select("Parent_Id=" + 0);
    foreach (DataRow dr in drowpar)
    {
        MenuItem objMenuItem = new MenuItem();
        objMenuItem.Text = dr["Page_Name"].ToString();
        objMenuItem.NavigateUrl = dr["Page_Url"].ToString();
        MenuBar.Items.Add(objMenuItem);
    }
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("Parent_Id >" + 0))
    {
        MenuItem objMenuItem = new MenuItem();
        objMenuItem.Text = dr["Page_Name"].ToString();
        objMenuItem.NavigateUrl = dr["Page_Url"].ToString();
        //MenuBar.FindItem(dr["Parent_Id"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(objMenuItem);
        MenuBar.FindItem(dr["Parent_Id"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(objMenuItem);
        //MenuBar.Items.Add(objMenuItem);
    }
```

i am binding asp.net menu control using database and getting this below in childitem binding to menu

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
 MenuBar.FindItem(dr["Parent_Id"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(objMenuItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message only happens for specific situations, and the possible reasons are:

- `objMenuItem` is null - which obviously in your code it is not
- `dr["Parent_Id"]` is null, and calling `ToString()` causes the error
- `MenuBar.FindItem(dr["Parent_Id"].ToString())` -  this isn't finding the item with the given parent ID
- The `ChildItems` collection on the menu item is null

If you want to be really sure where the object is not null, then you can do the following:

```
var id = dr["Parent_ID"].ToString();
var menuItem = MenuBar.FindItem(id);
if (menuItem != null)
    menuItem.ChildItems.Add(objMenuItem);
```

Having the code together masks where the actual error occurs.  Note, there is one other scenario where i didn't account for, which is the error is within the MenuBar itself, and it's masked.  Without seeing the full stack trace, it's hard to tell.  If you can post that, we can isolate it further.

Comment: foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("Parent_Id >" + 0))  this thing also making false your second condition. now tell me that thrid point where it is finding item?? in columns of my db?

Comment: Yup, the value being returned from Parent_Id isn't matched in the menubar, and thus finditem returns null.  When it returns null, accessing ChildItems blows up because the object is null.

Comment: no this is not Parent_Id>0 and all are given in my database

Comment: Updated above, I can only tell you why it happens, but if you use the update I have above, step through it and check out which line in the updated code it errors on.  Also post the stack trace to the error in the original post.